# How to extract XPATH or CSSPath from a web element in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-ide

I want to feed values to input fields which have no name, no id or no class.

```
<form class="formclass">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="password">
</form>`
```

Comment: To increase the chance of getting help, please include some current code of yours

Answer (score 1):

Try `XPath`

```
//form[@class="formclass"]/input[@type="text"]
//form[@class="formclass"]/input[@type="password"]
```

or `CSS` selector

```
form.formclass input[type="text"]
form.formclass input[type="password"]
```

Comment: what if we dont know about name of the form class? how can we get nearest identifier of an element(like id or name or class or xpath) to the element(input fields with no identifiers)?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

**xpath:**

```
(//form[@class='formclass]//input)[0] 
(//form[@class='formclass]//input)[1]
```

**css:**

```
.formclass input[type='text']
.formclass input[type='password']
```

Comment: Let us know it works, else will see where it went wrong

Comment: Please follow the link for basic's of locator findings
https://seleniummonk.blogspot.in/p/element-locators.html